# How to use `diff` on files whose paths contain whitespace

Tags: linux, perl, shell, unix

I am trying to find the differences between files, but the filename and directory name contain white space. I am trying to execute the command in a Perl script.

```
diff /home/users/feroz/logs/back_up20161112/Security File/General Security.csv /home/users/feroz/logs/back_up20161113/Security File/General Security.csv
```

#### Perl

```
open( my $FH, '>', $logfile ) or die "Cannot open the file '$logfile' $!";

foreach $filename ( keys %filenames ) {

    $old_file = $parent_directory . $previous_date . $search_directory . "$filenames{$filename}";
    $new_file = $parent_directory . $current_date . $search_directory . "$filenames{$filename}";

    if ( !-e $old_file ) {

        #print ("\nFile does not exist in previos date backup");

        print $FH "\nERROR:'$old_file' ---- does not exist in the backup directory ";
    }
    elsif ( !-e $new_file ) {

        #print ("\n The file does not exist in current directory");

        print $FH "\nERROR:'$new_file' --- does not exist in the present directory ";
    }
    else {

        # print $FH "\nDifference between the files $filenames{$filename} of  $previous_date and $current_date ";

        my $cmd = 'diff $old_file $new_file| xargs -0';
        open( my $OH, '|-', $cmd ) or die "Failed to read the output";
        while ( <OH> ) {
            print $FH "$_";
        }
        close $OH;
    }
}
```

Comment: `diff` is not a Perl command. Please show your real code.

Comment: diff is not perl command. I am trying to execute a unix command in perl scripts. I have mentioned perl scripts to check  if we have any option to ignore the white space

Comment: @ferozalam_82: That isn't relevant. Please show your real Perl code.

Comment: Here is my perl code

Comment: I have even tried the option xargs option for unix, i dont know if it works or not

Comment: Thank you. Single quotes don't interpolate, so that will pass the strings `$old_file` and `$new_file` to the command instead of those variables' contents. I have written a suggestion below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for showing your Perl code

Single quotes don't interpolate, so that will pass the strings `$old_file` and `$new_file` to the command instead of those variables' contents. The shell will then try to interpret them as shell variables

I suggest that you write this instead

```
my $cmd = qq{diff '$old_file' '$new_file' | xargs -0};
open( my $OH, '-|', $cmd ) or die "Failed to read the output";
```

That will use *double quotes* (`qq{...}`) around the command string so that the variables are interpolated. The file paths have single quotes around them to indicate that the shell should treat them as individual strings

This won't work if there's a chance that your file paths could contain a single quote, but that's highly unusual

Comment: Consider the case of deliberate attack -- ie. a file created with `touch $'$(rm -rf $HOME)\'$(rm -rf $HOME)\'.txt'` being passed as an argument to (or iterated over by) this script. It seems like teaching this technique is teaching how to create security flaws.

Answer (score 3):

To be absolutly safe, use  ShellQuote

```
use String::ShellQuote;

my $old_file2 = shell_quote($old_file);
my $new_file2 = shell_quote($new_file);
`diff $old_file2 $new_file2`;
```

Comment: So long as String::ShellQuote is correctly implemented for the shell providing `/bin/sh`, this is precisely as safe as my answer (either branch). +1.

Answer (score 2):

Pass arguments out-of-band to avoid the need to shell-quote them, rather than interpolating them into a string which is parsed by a shell as a script. Substituting filenames as literal text into a script generates exposure to shell [injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) -- the shell-scripting equivalent to the family of database security bugs known as [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/).

---

#### Without Any Shell At All

The pipe to `xargs -0` appears to be serving no purpose here. Eliminating it allows this to be run without any shell involved at all:

```
open(my $fh, "-|", "diff", $old_file, $new_file)
```

---

#### With Shell Arguments Passed Out-Of-Band From Script Text

If you really do want the shell to be invoked, the safe thing to do is to keep the script text an audited constant, and have it retrieve arguments from either the argv list passed to the shell or the environment.

```
# Putting $1 and $2 in double quotes ensures that the shell treats contents as literal
# the "_" is used for $0 in the shell.
$shell_script='diff "$1" "$2" | xargs -0'
open(my $fh, "-|",
  "sh", "-c", $shell_script,
  "_", $old_file, $new_file);
```

Comment: +1 for having the only answer that bypasses the shell; -1 for the shell bypass looking like an afterthought in your answer...

Comment: @oals, the OP's request involves running a pipeline; thus, the shell bypass approach is necessarily not literally responsive unless it's broken down into multiple forks.

Comment: I know, but the `xargs` seems to be a mistaken addition by the OP; it makes zero sense to me at least.

Comment: @oals, ...reordered, with the shell-free approach called out explicitly. Better?

Comment: Yes, very much so.

Answer (score 1):

You can either

1. Put the whitespace path segment inside quotes

   ```
   diff /home/users/feroz/logs/back_up20161112/"Security File"/General Security.csv /home/users/feroz/logs/back_up20161113/"Security File"/General Security.csv
   ```
2. or escape the whitespace

   ```
   diff /home/users/feroz/logs/back_up20161112/Security\ File/General Security.csv /home/users/feroz/logs/back_up20161113/Security\ File/General Security.csv`
   ```

Comment: Do we have any other option to ignore the white space  without manually editing it?

Comment: @ferozalam_82, well, the *ideal* thing to do is to invoke external programs without a shell involved, directly passing an `argv` array to be in turn passed to the `execv`-family syscall starting the program.